# Is it correct to emphasize with "do" when using the verb to be?

Tags: emphasis

I believe the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> I do like burgers.

Meaning that the speaker wants to emphasize that he likes burgers.

What about something like:

> I do am happy.
>
> She does is married.

when the speaker wants to emphasize their current situation? Is this grammatically correct? If not, are there any other alternatives to emphasize while using the verb *to be*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

The kind of emphasis you are talking about is called *verum focus* because it emphasizes the truth of the sentence being uttered.

In sentences with an auxiliary verb (*be*, *have*, or a modal verb like *might*, *can*, *must*, etc.) it is that auxiliary verb that gets focused.

The verb *do* is only used when there is no auxiliary verb in the sentence. This is the same *do* that shows up in questions and with negation.

So just like you can't say:

- *Does John be happy?
- *John doesn't be happy.

You also can't say:

- *John DOES be happy.

For sentences *with* auxiliary verbs, just focus the first auxiliary.

- John WILL leave today.
- John MIGHT have been watching TV.
- John IS happy.

Comment: Thank you @Alan Munn. Can you think of an alternative for this?

Comment: Just emphasize the auxiliary verb.  I'll add that to my answer more explicitly.

Comment: Note that all these are perfectly grammatical (if something old-fashioned) in Ireland, where _do be_ is used to express the consuetudinal present of _be_.

Comment: @Jorge You could add "so" as in:  "... will *so* leave...", " John is *so* happy..." or add an [intensifier](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/intensifiers) such as: *really*, *extremely* etc.

Answer (score 3):

"I am indeed happy", "She is indeed married".  you can move "indeed" around: "Indeed I am happy", "I am happy indeed".  The last has added emphasis on "happy" to my ear; it's like "I am happy, very happy" or "I am _definitely_happy!"

You can say "I, indeed, am happy", but it's a little more unusual.  It put the emphasis on "i".